# Inflate custom view android problems

Tags: android, view, inflate

i have extended view into a ScrollImageView. Then i put that into the xml:

In main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/my_xml" />

    <com.Android.Maps03.ScrollImageView
        android:id="@+id/BaseView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i want to work with that in the main activity like this:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ScrollImageView sIV = (ScrollImageView)findViewById(R.id.BaseView);
        Bitmap markerImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbase );
        sIV.setImage(markerImage);
```

When i run the app, the ScrollImage doesnt Appear.

The constructor of the clase (ScrollImageView) is this:

```
public ScrollImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context);
    initScrollImageView(context);

private void initScrollImageView(Context context) {
    mDisplay = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    mPadding = DEFAULT_PADDING;
}
```

do you have and idea?

Thanks.

Comment #1 Yes, i forget that, but i have the same problem.

Comment #2 No, im closing all the layout with the second />, not closing twice

Comment #3 This is the new logcat, i think this is the most remarkable entries.

Plz Help!

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but the super call should be super(context, attributeSet). The attributeSet has all the attributes from the xml.

Comment: You're also closing your ScrollImageView element twice.

Comment: @Gonzalo Diaz Harcha are you sure the current layout that is set defines the is the one that contains the scrollimageview?.. if it is having a problem somewhere along the object chain it would probably throw before you tried to find it, it sounds more like the view you are finding on doesn't contain the nested view and obviously casting a null to a type is never fun. So the view for your activity used `setContentView()` passing the containing view?

Comment: I put more code in the question. @Quintin Robinson i dont know if the layot contains the scrollimageview. The error log say this "The com.Android.Maps03.ScrollImageView failed to instatiate". I think that could be the problem. The set is setContentView(R.layout.main); the main.xml given by the program.

Comment: @Gonzalo Diaz Harcha Okay two things, you have expanded the line that throws the error, which line actually throws the exception? Also if you run the application in debug can you step into the `ScrollImageView` constructor and see if it exceptions at a particular line?

Comment: Is the activity attached to the window manager at the point your constructor is called? getSystemService() might be returning null...

Comment: I edited the questiong again. It isn the problem, there is a null here: ScrollImageView sIV = (ScrollImageView)findViewById(R.id.BaseView);

Comment: i Changued the question!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling setContentView in your Activity onCreate

Comment: I put the setContentView() before the pointer, so now i dont have the null pointer exception, but my ScrollImageView doesnt appear... :S

Comment: @Gonzalo Diaz Harcha Well it doesn't have any content inside what are you expecting to see?

Comment: i load the image resource. For example, if i call "...ScrollImageView sIV = new ScrollImageView(this); then setContentView(sIV); the view is perfect, and that is i want, but i need other things like buttons, not only that view. I thought that way will be better (Trying to put my ScrollImageView into the main.xml and call from there) but it doest have any good result. Do yo have an idea? thanks

Comment: it all looks good you just need to add stuff to the scrollview it is empty.